# It's eyed3 capable of acces all mp3 'standard' tags besides more common ones as 'title 'track'?

Tags: python, tags, mp3, eyed3

I succeed to tag the more "common" tags in mp3 files and the user-formatted ones.
But other standard ones as 'copyright', 'engineer', 'composer', 'encoded by', 'language'. are no showing (for example in EasyTag or other audio programs)
My lines are :

```
     t =Tag()
                t.artist = TAGS['AUTEUR']
                t.title = TAGS['TITLE']
                t.album = TAGS['ALBUM']
                t.genre = TAGS['GENRE']
                t.recording_date = TAGS['YEAR']
                t.track_num = TAGS['TRACK']
                t.publisher = TAGS['PUBLISHER']
                t.disc_num = (1, 1)
                t.user_text_frames.set(TAGS['CDID'], u"CD_ID")

 #These stick OK


                t.engineer = TAGS['ENG']
                t.copyright = TAGS['C']
                t.composer = TAGS['COMPOSER']
#no showing
                t.save(AUDIO, version=ID3_V2_3)
#I also test with version=ID3_V2_4 but no cigar.
```

It's eyed3 capable of access these tags?

Answer (score 0):

OK, really needing the 'Copyright' tag, i switch to 'Mutagen' module

All tags i needed are there, without the adding extra metadata creating 'user text frames' to store other important information.

Some ful recipe code to use Metagen here:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577138-embed-lyrics-into-mp3-files-using-mutagen-uslt-tag/

Forthe copyright, just:
...........

```
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, TCOP #... more imported tags here

try:
    tags = ID3(mp3file)
except ID3NoHeaderError:
    print "Adding ID3 header;",
    tags = ID3()
#... more tags        
tags["TCOP"] = TCOP(encoding=3, text=u"""All rights reserved. No part of this publication may be reproduced, distributed, or transmitted in any form or by any means, including photocopying, recording, or other electronic or mechanical methods, without the prior written permission of the publisher, except in the case of brief quotations embodied in critical reviews and certain other noncommercial uses permitted by copyright law. For permission requests, write to the publisher, addressed \“Attention: Permissions Coordinator,\” at the address below.""")
tags.save(mp3file)
```